# How to make xdebug not stop in the front controller of Symfony

Tags: symfony, netbeans, xdebug

I am working on a Symfony 2 project using Netbeans. When I debug the project, it always stops on the first line of the front controller (app_dev.php) even though there is no breakpoint.

Can it be fixed ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In NetBeans change setting for it
Tools->Options->PHP->Debugging->Stop at First Line